# Data does not get first time on StreamBuilder using Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I got follow code on my Flutter application. I am coding recipe application. Whenever I debug it, first time the snapshot return null. But second time snapshot return correct data. When My "malzemelerleAra" class run, "malzemeler" field does not get the data and return null exception.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:dropdownfield/dropdownfield.dart';
import 'package:tarifler/utilities/constants.dart';

class MalzemelerleAra extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MalzemelerleAraState();
}

int _count = 0;

class _MalzemelerleAraState extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<Widget> extractedChildren = <Widget>[
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          GetMalzemeler(),
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.green,
            onPressed: () => _changeListCount(true),
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
          ),
          FlatButton(
            color: Colors.red,
            onPressed: () => _changeListCount(false),
            child: Icon(Icons.remove),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      _malzemeAlani(),
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < _count; ++i) {
      extractedChildren.add(_malzemeAlani());
    }

    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: extractedChildren,
      ),
    );
  }

  _malzemeAlani() {
    String malzeme_id;
    Constants constt = new Constants();
    List<String> malzemeler;
    if (constt.malzemeler == null) {
      malzemeler = ["example"];
    }
    else{
      malzemeler = constt.malzemeler;
    }
    return DropDownField(
      onValueChanged: (dynamic value) {
        malzeme_id = value;
      },
      value: malzeme_id,
      required: false,
      hintText: "Malzeme Seç",
      labelText: "Malzemeler",
      items: malzemeler,
    );
  }

  _changeListCount(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      if (value) {
        _count++;
      } else if (!value) {
        _count--;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Constant class:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Constants {
  List<dynamic> malzemeler;
  DocumentReference reference;
  Constants (){}

  Constants.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, {this.reference})
      : assert(map["malzemeler"] != null),
        malzemeler = map["malzemeler"];

  Constants.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot)
      : this.fromMap(snapshot.data, reference: snapshot.reference);
}

class GetMalzemeler extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => GetMalzemelerState();
}

class GetMalzemelerState extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection("malzemeler").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return LinearProgressIndicator();
        } else {
          final getMalzemeler = Constants.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(0));
          print(getMalzemeler.malzemeler);
          return Text("example");
        }
      },
    );

  }


}
```

This my firebase database:
[image]
Thank you for support

When I tried first answer, I am taking still this error.

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#f5a3f):
The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
    GetMalzemeler 
lib\screens\malzemelerleAra.dart:19
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod  (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      GetMalzemelerState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:tarifler/utilities/constants.dart:28
#2      StreamBuilder.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:425
#3      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/async.dart:125
#4      StatefulElement.build 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4047
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 99765 pixels on the right.
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was
    ListView
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `!snapshot.hasData` to

```
if(snapshot.data.documents.length > 0) {
   final getMalzemeler = Constants.fromSnapshot(snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(0));
      print(getMalzemeler.malzemeler);
      return Text("example");
} else {
     return LinearProgressIndicator();
}
```